# How to increase the strength of a baked fcurve?

Tags: animation, baking

I baked an audio file to an object's Z location, however it results in very small values (mostly less than `.1`).
How can I increase (multiply) the values resulting from the baked fcurve?

I suppose I could bake it to another object (e.g. an empty) and then use a driver to do the multiplication, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the F-curve on the Y axis (the Y axis of the curve, not the affected object)? I've used this a few times, but not with a baked F-curve. Select the entire curve and set the pivot point to 2D cursor, then `S` `Y` `value`. I can't take a screenshot right now, but the controls are analogous to those in the 3D view.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Baked F-curves are pretty much un-editable for some reason..

Comment: I found a tutorial that claims to solve that. http://youtu.be/V3fRrvs7hM4?t=6m10s

Comment: @SixthOfFour I guess that would work.. Though I think it might increase the size of the file a lot (I have many objects with baked curves). I might rather use drivers..

Comment: I hope you'll be able to use the same multiplier for them all then, so you won't have to write 200 drivers.

Comment: @SixthOfFour I'm doing this all via python anyway, so I shouldn't have to :P

Comment: I think I have found the problem. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/finding-maximum-and-minimum-of-an-f-curve-baked-from-an-audio-file#comment36087_24460

Answer (score 5):

This Problem i solved yesterday. The easiest way without addons or math,  - is to use f curve modifier ,in this case "envelope". You set the reference area ( dottet blacklines) and than you click "add control point. These are manipulated with min and max value buttons. You must play with that. The result should be distorted translated or cutoff curves.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40655/combine-f-curve-modifiers-with-baked-sound). To summarize what's there, and what I've read elsewhere, there are three options:

1. Similar to what you suggested, create a custom property, bake your sound to the property, then create a driver with a simple python expression to drive other properties at the required scale. This is what I did. Details in the link above.
2. Use the [Sound Drivers add-on](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?236729-AddOn-Sound-Drivers-(-formerly-speaker-tools-)). (I haven't tried it, but it looks nice!)
3. After baking, un-bake the sound to a normal F-Curve. Then you can scale it or edit details.

P.S. For my project, I tried to do this with the Extended Polynomial Generator F-Curve modifier, but it didn't work... Not sure why, maybe I didn't understand how generators are supposed to work, or maybe they only work on normal F-Curves.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for 3rd option: Graph Editor / Key / Un-Bake Curve