# How can I automate a audio file to transformations?

Tags: animation, transforms, audio

So I am lip syncing, and I am not exactly doing a traditional mouth, I have a single light, and lets say on it's y axis I set a boundary from 0 to 10, then I get an audio file and say at no volume the object is a y = 0, while a max volume y = 10? And of course everything else in between. Would it be possible to do any of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bake Sound to FCurve**

Add a single keyframe to the Y location,  open the graph editor and choose ["Bake Sound to Fcurve"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/editing.html#bake-sound-to-f-curves) from the graph editors "Key" menu.

To change the range of the baked fcurve add an [envelope modifier.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#envelope)

[Combine F-Curve Modifiers with baked Sound](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40655/combine-f-curve-modifiers-with-baked-sound)

[What's the range of values on a sound-baked f-curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/whats-the-range-of-values-on-a-sound-baked-f-curve)

[Rescaling a baked F-curve to values between 0 and 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/rescaling-a-baked-f-curve-to-values-between-0-and-1)