# Combine F-Curve Modifiers with baked Sound

Tags: python, particles, keyframes, audio, fcurves

I have a Particle System on a grid with an *X Velocity* of `200` and a *Tangent* of `60`. The *Tangent* has a keyframe with a sound baked to the f-curve.

The problem is the *Tangent* get set around `1` instead of `60`. I want the sound curve to modify the `60` by a factor around `1.25`. That way the *Tangent* moves between `60` and `75`. Also I want more particles to be emitted when the sound is loud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an envelope modifier to the baked fcurve to remap to your desired range.

Another way, and one I use extensively in my sound drivers addon, is to bake the sound to a custom property `prop`, then set up a driver , `SCRIPTED EXPRESSION` type, with the baked property as a variable (`SINGLE_PROPERTY` type) `var`  datapath `'["prop"]'` and make the expression `60 * var`.

(`var` and `prop` are only suggested names for example case)

To add and bake a property, choose the object you are going to bake on, open the "Custom Properties" Panel, add a property, key in a number, make it a float type (eg 0.0) and then add a keyframe. Select and Bake to Sound from the graph editor as you would any other property.

You can see the datapath on the active fcurve properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> used for the datapath of the driver variable,  or use the copy data path on mouse menu of the custom property field, and paste  into the datapath field of the driver variable.

Go one level further and add another custom property and use it in the driver as the multiplier, then you can change the amplitude of the baked fcurve effect directly from a slider in the UI.

To make it easier I have put together an addon, [Sound Drivers](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?236729-AddOn-Sound-Drivers-(-formerly-speaker-tools-)).

This post is also relevant to  [What's the range of values on a sound-baked f-curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/whats-the-range-of-values-on-a-sound-baked-f-curve/39241#39241) .

Comment: How do I bake the sound to a custom property? Is that something I need to do in the text editor? Because I don't have much experience with the text editor (not that I'm hesitant to try, though).

Comment: Edited answer with details of how to bake custom prop.

Comment: So, I don't know what's wrong, but I followed your instructions and the `prop` variable seems to change correctly, but it just won't link to `var`. [Here](https://goo.gl/rElUWe) is a picture of the graph editor. See anything wrong?

Comment: Aww yea! Now we're talkin! Thanks so much for your help.