# Issues with F-Curve to bake sound frequency?

Tags: animation, audio, fcurves

I am trying to bake the sound with some force field empty and a sphere, making them react to certain frequencies, following the tutorial posted in this link:

http://barneyisbo.blogspot.com/2013/11/tutorial-of-audio-visualization-in.html

My main issue is after I try and animate the scaling, even if i have set the scale value to be high like 2 or 3 or something, once I assign the baked value the scale size becomes very small and am unable to see them properly
[image]

[image]

The scale values were all 1 before i baked them to certain frequencies, I am super confused and  have wasted too much time trying to figure this out lol

Comment: Can add an envelope or generator modifier to the baked fcurve to amplify it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/how-to-increase-the-strength-of-a-baked-fcurve

Comment: what about providing your blend file?